# Angular + Flask : Not able to iterate variable when integrated with flask

Tags: angularjs, flask

I created a small AngularJS project using some code from a tutorial and made small changes to it. But when I integrate the same with Flask, I get undefinedError : todo1 is undefined

#### Server

```
@app.route("/register")
def registeredDevices():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

#### Client

register.html

```
<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.3.0" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

     <script src="/static/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>


    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="/static/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TodoController">
    <h1>Todos</h1>

    <div id='content'>
    <div>
        <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' placeholder='enter serial'/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='todo1 in filteredTodos | filter:searchText'>{{todo1.text}}</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
        data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
        data-boundary-links="true"></div>
     </div>
   </body>
```

script.js

```
var todos = angular.module('todos', ['ui.bootstrap']);

todos.controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
   $scope.filteredTodos = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 10
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;

  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
      $scope.todos.push({ text:'todo'+i, done:false});
    }
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 

  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.todos.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };

  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that `{{todo1}}` is both Angular and Jinja2 syntax. At the time the Jinja2 template engine sees the `{{todo1}}`, the variable has not been defined, since it will be created in the browser, in JavaScript, by AngularJS.

For solutions, see for example: http://lorenhoward.com/blog/how-to-get-angular-to-work-with-jinja/

You have to have a basic understanding of how a web application works. The python/flask/jinja2 part runs on the server. Jinja2 tries to generate html and sees ``{{ something }}`. It will try to replace that with the value of a Python variable called "something". If it works, your code will (hopefully) return a page with HTML to the browser.

In the browser (client side) you have AngularJS. It also looks for things like `{{something}}`. But these will normally already have been replaced by jinja2. So that is why you need the workarounds in the link.

Comment: thanks a lot rje..awesome learning..but could you please elaborate more on that..like sometimes I dont see the conflict happening and sometimes it appears..it would be really helpful for everyone.

Comment: Added a little more explanation.